# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'amount'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, valueerror

I have a dataframe with transaction_id , created_at, and amount column of type float.
I write the is dataframe to csv then want to load it through the following pd.read_csv code. It keeps on showing the error: cannot convert string to float.

```
feature_columns_dtype = {
'transaction_id'                     :'object',
'created_at'                         :'object' ,
'amount'                             :'float64'}

label_column_dtype = {"is_fraud": "int64"}

raw_data = [
        pd.read_csv(
            file,
            header=None,
            names=feature_columns_names + [label_column],
            dtype=merge_two_dicts(feature_columns_dtype, label_column_dtype),
            skiprows=[1],
            low_memory=False
        )
        for file in input_files
    ]
    concat_data = pd.concat(raw_data)
```

I have checked the original dataframe and ensured the right datatypes are enforced and the 'amount' column is casted to np.float64.

I removed NAs, removed the first row of the data, added low_memory = false option to read_csv as suggested in previous answers to similar questions, but the error still persists.

Any clue what causes this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are sure the `amount` dtype is right something goes wrong. I propose a solution to debug bad values using `converters` parameter of `pd.read_csv` function:

`data.csv`:

```
1,2023-03-21,$1000,1
2,2023-03-21,500,0
```

Note the third column of the first row contains a leading `$` so it can't be converted to float as it.

```
def check_amount(amount):
    try:
        return float(amount)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'"{amount}" cannot be converted to float')

df = pd.read_csv(
            'data.csv',
            header=None,
            names=feature_columns_names + [label_column],
            dtype=merge_two_dicts(feature_columns_dtype, label_column_dtype),
            skiprows=[1],
            low_memory=False
            converters={'amount': check_amount}
    )
```

Output:

```
"$1000" cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: tried that & got to the error .. reason it was still considering the column headers and removing the next row so it was simply the column name causing this error .. thank you!

Comment: To elaborate more on the final solution, in my case column names were causing the error. so either explicitly remove them when writing the dataframe to csv with 'header=False' option in to_csv or remove them when reading the file by keeping header=True as default to treat column names as header and not row values, or  if you specify header=False then add 'skiprows=[0]' in the call to read_csv to remove the row with column names.

Comment: Ok. That's why it's better to post data source.